# I wanted to format two subfigures with \hspace*{\fill}, but they somehow do not start at the same line. Why?

Tags: spacing, floats, subfloats

This is the used code (which makes no sense, but I just wanted to figure out how this works)

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{16244301_1232446016821513_2141044701_n.png}
\label{fig:subim1}
\caption{Hello a chameleon}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{16244301_1232446016821513_2141044701_n.png}
\label{fig:subim2}
\caption{Hello a chameleon}
\hspace*{\fill}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: The second `\hspace*{\fill}` is inside the `subfigure` environment while the first is outside.

Answer (score 2):

The first `\hspace` is outside the `subfigure`, the second is inside. Because of that you get an empty line inside the second `subfigure`, below the caption. If you add `\fbox{ .. }` around each `subfigure` this becomes obvious:

[image]

(The images are black rectangles because I used the `demo` option for `graphicx`.)

So if you move the second `\hspace` to after `\end{subfigure}`, the output is probably more as expected.

On the other hand, if your objective is to horizontally center the subfigures, why not use `\centering`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\hspace*{\fill}
\fbox{\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{16244301_1232446016821513_2141044701_n.png}
\label{fig:subim1}
\caption{Hello a chameleon}
\end{subfigure}}
\fbox{\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{16244301_1232446016821513_2141044701_n.png}
\label{fig:subim2}
\caption{Hello a chameleon}
\end{subfigure}}
\hspace*{\fill}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{16244301_1232446016821513_2141044701_n.png}
\label{fig:subim1}
\caption{Hello a chameleon}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{16244301_1232446016821513_2141044701_n.png}
\label{fig:subim2}
\caption{Hello a chameleon}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel a bit stupid I didnt see that haha

Answer (score 0):

Better i used `\centering` for figure content, image width determine with `subfigure` width and use `\hfil` for distance between images:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{showframe} % for show page layout
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{16244301_1232446016821513_2141044701_n.png}
\label{fig:subim1}
\caption{Hello a chameleon}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{16244301_1232446016821513_2141044701_n.png}
\label{fig:subim2}
\caption{Hello a chameleon}
\end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]